Бэкенд или фронтенд должен объединять таблицы по FK?
В бэкенде сервиса есть две таблицы БД связанные отношением один ко многим.
table1
- PK: int
- name: string

table2
- PK: int
- name: string
- FK: table1

В сервисе есть API позволяющие получить данные этих таблиц на фронтенд.
Если требуется вывести на фронтенде данные обеих таблиц в объединенном виде по FK, то какие могут быть причине не делать новый API который даст эти данные в нужном виде:
t1.name, t2.name

Т.е. какие могут быть причины, чтобы фронтенд получал данные таблиц из существующих API и сам делал объединение таблиц?

Подумайте о производительности. Один запрос с джойном в базу данных наверняка будет легче, чем несколько простых. Но многое зависит от типа БД.

Ну в целом это какая-то ерунда - делать на фронте работу бэкэнда. Или даже работу БД. Если вам нужен поиск каких-то записей в БД, плюс соединение таблиц, плюс пагинация, плюс... Лучше всё это делать на бэкенде и отдавать фронту конкретный кусок данных. Нет никакого смысла гонять на фронт тучу данных, чтобы там уже их как-то обрабатывать. Фронт должен получать готовые данные и только нужный кусок. Потому что траффик должен быть минимальным и загруженность фронта должна быть минимальной. Исключение - какие-то мелкие справочники, которые всегда сразу целиком показываются на фронте.

@CrazyElf Ну в целом это какая-то ерунда - делать на фронте работу бэкэнда - это называется толстый клиент - и еще совсем недавно было очень популярно

@Grundy В каких-то специализированных клиент-серверных решениях (на производстве или ещё где) - да не вопрос. А так то да, забыл я уже про толстый и тонкий клиент, была такая тема. )

Нет никаких причин для того, чтобы нагружать фронтэнд знанием о структуре БД. БЭ должен по простому запросу от ФЭ предоставлять нужные данные, при этом ФЭ всё равно, как и откуда они взялись.

Сервер занимается обработкой данных, запросами к базе данных и подготовкой данных для отправки клиенту. Клиент же занимает обработкой данных, для наилучшего представления их конечному пользователю.
Как ответ на ваш вопрос, сервер должен делать запросы к БД, объединять таблицы и группировать данных и передавать их в минимально-полном виде клиенту для отображения
